# Spring Boot Logs directed to Tomcat Catalina.out log

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, tomcat9

I am facing a logging issue with my Spring Boot application deployed on an external Tomcat 9 server.
The application is writing the logs to catalina.out file and not to the file mentioned in log4j2.properties.

Please help in identifying what am I missing.
Below is the code.

log4j2.properties

```
status = debug
name = PropertiesConfig

property.dir = /var/log

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = LogToRollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${dir}/bt4test.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${dir}/bt4test-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1000MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = fileLogger
#### Class/Package Level logging control
logger.fileLogger.name = com.example
logger.fileLogger.level = debug
logger.fileLogger.additivity = false
logger.fileLogger.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingFile
```

Spring Boot Initializer Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServletInitializer.class.getName());
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        logger.info("ServletInitializer");
        
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

Rest Controller Class

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
        "com.example.*"
    }
)
public class Bt4TestEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Bt4TestEndpoint.class.getName());

    static {
        logger.info("hello static");
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        logger.info("hello");
        
        return "hello";
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>BT4test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>BT4test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>bt4test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>    
                    <mainClass>com.example.ServletInitializer</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What happens if you run it from IDE or shell? Where is the log written?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the log4j2 related jars & log4j2.xml in the tomcat app server and make these available through setenv.sh file with the relative paths.

Once Jar's & xml are available to the environment then it will start writing as per the configuration.

For Example:

### setenv.sh

export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/log4j2/lib/*:$CATALINA_HOME/log4j2/conf/"

- Please note that lib folder holds all the libraries of log4j2 & Configurations folder holds the log4j2.xml. Moreover, create log4j2 folder under Catalina home directory.

## use the logging manager from log4j-jul

LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you provide code snippets to better explain your solution?

Comment: Updated the post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When Spring Boot initializes Log4j 2.x, it uses its own lookup list for configuration files: see [`Log4jLoggingSystem#getCurrentlySupportedConfigLocations()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/484050347a919e15c16885b14472e557461cccc9/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/Log4J2LoggingSystem.java#L113) for a list. While usually the list of files is larger than the one used by Log4j 2.x (`log4j2-test.*`, `log4j2.*` and `log4j2-spring.*`) in OP's case the `*.properties` files are not detected.

Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.4 or higher, which includes [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/2cb4403cd0a34102c8df3c724ad13f9950510fe4) should solve the problem.