# Logs not written to a log file : Spring boot and log4j.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, log4j2, java-11

my log4j.properties

```
status=error
name=PropertiesConfig
filters=threshold
filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=debug
appenders=console,rolling
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0}|%-5p|%c{1}|%M|%L|%replace{%m}{\r}{ }%n
# Rotate log file
appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.rolling.name=LogToRollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName=/var/logs/app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=/var/logs/backup/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0}|%-5p|%c{1}|%M|%L|%replace{%m}{\r}{ }%n
appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max=5
#loggers = rolling
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
#logger.appenderRefs=rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=LogToRollingFile
```

Dependecies :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Log4 file is getting picked and i can see logs getting printed in the desired format, but file appender is not working .

what is being missed by me ?

Comment: Please add the versions of Spring and Log4j2 used. Is the `log4j2.properties` file read twice? On older Spring Boot releases Spring didn't support the `*.properties` format (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743682/11748454)).

Comment: version for spring boot is 2.6.3

Comment: okay , just use logging.config=classpath:log4j2-dev.properties in application properties file as per env. solved issue for me.